# How to pass multiple dropdown values as URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm basically trying to create a form , with 2 dropdowns and pass the values from select as URL parameters through a from submit button ,

```html
 <form action="">
 <select id="Select1">
         <option value="1">Tshirt</option>
         <option value="2">Hat</option>
         <option value="3">Sweater</option>
         <option value="4">Hoodie</option>
      </select>
      <select id="Select2">
         <option value="1">Red</option>
         <option value="2">Yellow</option>
         <option value="3">Pink</option>
      </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

1. If none of the dropdowns are selected , the url should be : domain.com
2. If the first value is selected , the url should be : domain.com/Tshirt
3. Otherwise if both options are selected , the url should be : domain.com/Tshirt/Red

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Additionally, it looks like you've asked many questions without accepting answers. Please go through your old questions and click the empty check mark next to the most appropriate answer, to help other people find the answer in the future.

Comment: "pass the values from select as URL parameters through a from submit button" Where? how? why?

Comment: @AndyRay with the javascript part mostly , I still don't find myself to be quite confident on JS , 2. Was not aware of that , will do , thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Mike Your question will be closed unless you post the javascript code you've tried and which part of it you're having trouble with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `click` event listener on submit button and get `text` property of selected dropdown option.

```js
const submitBtn = document.querySelector("#submitBtn");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const select1 = document.querySelector("#Select1");
  const select2 = document.querySelector("#Select2");
  const val1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].text ?? "";
  const val2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].text ?? "";
  const url = `domain.com/${val1}/${val2}`;
  console.log(url);
})
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

 <select id="Select1">
         <option value="1">Tshirt</option>
         <option value="2">Hat</option>
         <option value="3">Sweater</option>
         <option value="4">Hoodie</option>
      </select>
      <select id="Select2">
         <option value="1">Red</option>
         <option value="2">Yellow</option>
         <option value="3">Pink</option>
      </select>
        <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much , exactly what I was looking for